# Time Complexity - Which between these two algorithms is faster?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, foreach

**Description**

> The goal of this program is to populate an orderList from the users
>   orders and a productList foreach of those order. (Please ignore possible syntax errors from this pseudo-C#-code)

**Data Structures**

```
class User {
    List<Order> orders; 
}

class Order {
    List<Product> products;
}

class Product {
    int price;
}

List<User> userList = GetUsersFromDB();

List<Order> orderList     = new List<Order>();  
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
```

**First Version**

```
foreach(User u in userList) {
    foreach(Order o in u.orders) {
        orderList.Add(o);
        foreach(Product p in o.products) {
            productList.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Version**

```
foreach(User u in userList) {
    foreach(Order o in u.orders) {
        orderList.Add(o);
    }
}

foreach(Order o in orderList) {
    foreach(Product p in o.products) {
        productList.Add(p);
    }
}
```

**My thoughts**

- First  program T(n) = O(n^3)
- Second program T(n) = O(n^2) + O(n^2) < O(n^3)

> Therefore the second program is faster, correct?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What does n denote ? And is the operation Add performed in constant time ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Im assuming the length of the lists. Technically it should be `O(u*o*p)`

Comment: @Mitchel0022: sorry, I am asking the OP.

Comment: As a complete aside if efficiency is the name of the game, you'd be better to implement vanilla `for` loops over `foreach` as `foreach` will create enumerator instances. A small overhead but there nonetheless...

Comment: In theory, both have same worst-case time complexity- `O(|U|.|O|.|P|)`. Benchmark it, you may see a little bit of difference but may not be significant for large data.

Answer (score 7):

**Overview**

Your analysis for the second case is wrong. Since you have one entry in orderlist for each of the inner things of the first loop the `foreach(Order o in orderList)` is looping over n^2 items. Having said that there is a disclaimer that n isn't very meaningful here since it is representing multiple things.

Better is to look at it using u, o and p instead.

**Case 1**

The first one is clearly `O(uop)`.

**Case 2**

This case has two sets of loops. The first pair of loops is `O(uo)` as you'd expect..

The second pair of loops then starts with a loop of `uo` items and then an inner loop of O(p) so the second pair is `O(uop)`. Overall this makes it `O(uo)+O(uop)` which is equivalent to `O(uop)`, the same as case 1.

Essentially the second case just moves things around a bit, it hasn't actually changed the fundamental algorithm at all.

**Real world**

As always though if you are actually caring about real world performance rather than just theoretical algorithmic complexity (which isn't always useful when looking at specific cases) then benchmark the performance of your two techniques.

Comment: Isn't the second case `uo` + `op`?

Comment: @FatihAkici: the second case has two sets of loops.The first pair of loops are `uo` as you'd expect. The second pair though loops over orderList which we know has `uo` items in it hence it is actually `uop`. So overall it is `uo+uop` which is equivalent to `uop`. I'll see if I can explain that a bit better in my answer.

Comment: @FatihAkici: I've updated the answer to hopefully be clearer. Let me know if you think it still needs more work.

Comment: Oh the last loop is iterating over orderList, not orders. My bad, thanks for clarifica+1on!

Comment: @FatihAkici: No problem. I got confused by that first time reading the question too - I was like "This isn't even doing the same thing!" :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, anyway I resolved using parallel foreach